# Removing child from parent node Swift 2

Tags: swift

I am trying to update my score label at the end of the game. Since the variable (seems to be) outside of the scope I figured I would just remove the label and make a new one in the `adjust` function. I am not familiar with swift and would appreciate help. Can I just reposition or do I have to create new label? Cant figure it out. Thanks

```
func loadScore() {
    let scoreBand = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")
    scoreBand.name = StickHeroGameSceneChildName.ScoreName.rawValue
    scoreBand.text = "0"
    scoreBand.position = CGPointMake(0, DefinedScreenHeight / 2 - 200)
    scoreBand.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    scoreBand.fontSize = 100
    scoreBand.zPosition = StickHeroGameSceneZposition.ScoreZposition.rawValue
    scoreBand.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Center

    addChild(scoreBand)
}
func adjustScore() {
    //var scoreBand = scoreBand
    scoreBand.position = CGPointMake(0, DefinedScreenHeight / 2 - 100)//doesnt recognize scoreBand

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reposition, just declare `scoreBand` as a variable of your containing class. For example:

```
class SomeClass: SKSpriteNode {

    var scoreBand: SKLabelNode!

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        scoreBand = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")

        super.init(size: size)

        anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self 
    }

    func loadScore() {
        scoreBand.name = StickHeroGameSceneChildName.ScoreName.rawValue
        scoreBand.text = "0"
        scoreBand.position = CGPointMake(0, DefinedScreenHeight / 2 - 200)
        scoreBand.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        scoreBand.fontSize = 100
        scoreBand.zPosition = StickHeroGameSceneZposition.ScoreZposition.rawValue
        scoreBand.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Center

        addChild(scoreBand)
    }

    func adjustScore() {
        scoreBand.position = CGPointMake(0, DefinedScreenHeight / 2 - 100)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks carter, It brought up another error, I edited your answer with the error it brought. sorry to new this site

Comment: @hahu It's all good! Usually edits are made on your original question, not the answers. Regardless, I've updated my answer to fix the error you're having.